# Wordpress Permission nightmare on Centos 7

Tags: wordpress, file-permissions, centos7

I have an installation of wordpress on a remote server on

```
 /var/www/html/site.com/public_html
```

with a virtual host that point to this folder  with AllowOverride All

the pointing works.

now i have set ownership of all folder to the user:apache
and included the user in the apache group

```
 all folder are setted to 755 
 and file to 644
 wp-config.php to 440
 wp-content to apache and 755
```

The problem arrives when i try to download plugin/themes  upload photos ecc. form the interface.

I have created even sftp server on the machine and setted an rsa_key in user folder.

then with plugin ssh-sftp-updater-support I have enabled ssh2 but the error says "could not create directory"

can someone help me out on this nightmare?

Answer (score 0):

Under which user is PHP running? If it's not apache, then it can't create directories because it's not owner (755 permission). To see the user under which the PHP is running try the following code

```
<?php
system('/usr/bin/id');
?>
```

The server may use `mod_ruid` or `suEXEC` to allow PHP to run under different users.

If PHP is indeed running under something else than apache, you will need to change the ownership or chmod the folders to 777.

Comment: it's apache
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache) context=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0...

Comment: This looks OK. Does it work if you change folder permissions to 777? If it doesn't work even with 777, then it's probably an FTP issue. Check if sftp is allowed to write files. The setting is in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file, search for `write_enable` and set it to `write_enable=YES`.